# Problem with tikz image in beamer.

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, tikz-arrows, tikz-matrix

I really hope you guys can help me out here. I have a tikz picture which is working mighty fine in the standard article mode using the following packages/libraries:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
```

But when I try to transfer these file to a beamer document, I'm unable to compile for reasons unknown.

Here is the code for one of the images which are not working in beamer with the packages/libraries mentioned above.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
plain/.style={
  draw=none,
  fill=none,
  },
dot/.style={draw,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0,fill=black
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
  nodes={
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep=8.5pt
    },
 nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt
  },
>=latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
|[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Input\\layer}
          & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Hidden\\layer}
                       & |[plain]| \parbox{1cm}{\centering Output\\layer} \\
       & |[plain]|                \\
|[plain]| &            & |[plain]|   \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]|  & |[plain]|   \\
|[plain]| & |[dot]|                  \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]|  & |[plain]|   \\
          & |[dot]|    &           \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]|  & |[plain]|   \\
|[plain]| & |[dot]|    & |[plain]|   \\
|[plain]| & |[plain]|  & |[plain]|   \\
|[plain]| &            & |[plain]|    \\
          & |[plain]|                 \\
};




\draw[<-o] (mat-2-1) -- node[above] {Open price $x_1$} +(-3cm,0);
\draw[<-o] (mat-7-1) -- node[above] {High price $x_2$} +(-3cm,0);
\draw[<-o] (mat-12-1) -- node[above] {Low price $x_3$} +(-3cm,0);

\foreach \i in {2,7,12}
    {  \draw[->] (mat-\i-1) -- (mat-3-2);
    \draw[->] (mat-\i-1) -- (mat-11-2);
      }
\foreach \ai in {3,11}
  {  \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-7-3);
      }

      \draw[->] (mat-7-3) -- node[above] {Closing price $y_t$} +(3cm,0) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

My initial guess is that there is a problem with:

```
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
```

What seems weird to me is that it's working outside of beamer.

Thank you in advance! A quick response is much appreciated!

Comment: Please complete your example to become an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). Otherwise potential helpers need to do this for you in order to be able to experiment with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is that `&` is redefined inside the TikZ `matrix`. Consider these quotes from the manuals of `beamer` and TikZ, respectively:

> You must also use the `[fragile]` option for frames that include any “fragile” text, which is any text that is
>   not “interpreted the way text is usually interpreted by TEX.” For example, if you use a package that (locally)
>   redefined the meaning of, say, the character `&`, you must use this option.

(`beamer` manual, section 12.9 *Verbatim and Fragile Text*)

> Even though TikZ seems to use & to separate cells, `pgf` actually uses a different command to separate cells,
>   namely the command `\pgfmatrixnextcell` and using a normal `&` character will normally fail. What happens
>   is that, TikZ makes `&` an active character and then defines this character to be equal to `\pgfmatrixnextcell`.
>   In most situations this will work nicely, but sometimes `&` cannot be made active;[...]

(`pgfmanual.pdf`, section 20.5 *Considerations Concerning Active Characters*)

In other words, for your existing code to work, you have to add the `fragile` option to the `frame` environment, i.e. `\begin{frame}[fragile]`.

The other option you have is define a different method of separating cells in the `matrix`, using the `ampersand replacement` key. Add e.g.

```
 ampersand replacement=\&,
```

to the `net` style, and use `\&` instead of `&`.

In the code below I also converted the arrow head syntax from the old and deprecated `arrows` library to the syntax provided by the new `arrows.meta` library. (Cf. chapter 40 *Arrow tip library* in `pgfmanual`.) You can reduce the amount of code a bit by setting a specific style for the first row (see code). And finally instead of adding the `plain` style to nearly all the cells, why not let that be the default, and just add `|[draw]|` to those few cells where you need it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
dot/.style={draw,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0,fill=black
  },
net/.style={
  matrix of nodes,
 ampersand replacement=\&,
  nodes={
    circle,
    inner sep=8.5pt,
    },
 nodes in empty cells,
  column sep=0.6cm,
  row sep=-11pt,
  row 1/.style={nodes={text width=1cm,align=center}}
  },
>=Latex
]
\matrix[net] (mat)
{
   {Input\\ layer} \& {Hidden\\layer} \& {Output\\layer} \\ % braces are needed around content to not start new row in matrix
|[draw]| \&                               \\
         \& |[draw]|  \&                  \\
         \&           \&                  \\
         \& |[dot]|                       \\
         \&           \&                  \\
|[draw]| \& |[dot]|   \& |[draw]|         \\
         \&           \&                  \\
         \& |[dot]|   \&                  \\
         \&           \&                  \\
         \& |[draw]|  \&                  \\
|[draw]| \&                               \\
};


\draw[<-{Circle[open]}] (mat-2-1) -- node[above] {Open price $x_1$} +(-3cm,0);
\draw[<-{Circle[open]}] (mat-7-1) -- node[above] {High price $x_2$} +(-3cm,0);
\draw[<-{Circle[open]}] (mat-12-1) -- node[above] {Low price $x_3$} +(-3cm,0);

\foreach \i in {2,7,12}
 {
  \draw[->] (mat-\i-1) -- (mat-3-2);
  \draw[->] (mat-\i-1) -- (mat-11-2);
 }
\foreach \ai in {3,11}
   \draw[->] (mat-\ai-2) -- (mat-7-3);


\draw[->] (mat-7-3) -- node[above] {Closing price $y_t$} +(3cm,0) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @Torbørn T. for your quick response.

Comment: @LeonardAukea Instead of posting a “Thank you” as a comment, you should consider accepting it (by clicking on the checkmark ✓) if it solved your problem.